# Filtrar solo texto de una columna alfanumérica en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

¿cómo puedo crear una función que permita obtener el CURP a 15 dígitos (sin el homoclave) ya que el CURP contiene 18 dígitos y solo es necesario mostrar 15 dígitos que pasen como parámetro la identificación de usuario es decir la Id del participante estoy trabajando en mysql

esta es mi tabla donde se encuentra el crup

```
CREATE TABLE Participante(
        Id              INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        Nombre          VARCHAR(50),
        ApellidoP       VARCHAR(50),
        ApellidoM       VARCHAR(50),
        Email           VARCHAR(150),
        Telefono        INT(30),
        Curp            VARCHAR(150),
        IdColonia       INT,
        primary key(Id),
        CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (IdColonia) REFERENCES Colonia(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );
```

y esto es lo que llevo de la funcion

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  FUNCTION CURP(inNombre varchar(100), inId int) RETURNS varchar(15)
begin
declare nombre varchar(20);
set nombre=inNombre<15;
return nombre;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Puntos a mencionar:

- La función recibe como argumento la columna que modificará con la lógica interna que tu programes
- Para filtrar y solo devolver la CURP fomateada de algún usuario ocuparás en el `SELECT` el filtro de `WHERE`
- Usaremos la función [`mysql regexp_replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) para indicar la columna que se desea formatear(**la CURP**) el patrón a buscar(**los números que de ella debe quitar**) y el valor de reemplazo de este (**una cadena vacia**)
- Como el valor devuelto estará formateado entonces le indicamos que la función retorna un valor no deterministico
- Debemos limitar a 1 el retorno de resultados de la función para que con esto evitemos el error de: *returns more than 1 row*

Entonces la función debería verse así:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION formateaCURP(curp VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE formateo VARCHAR(100);
    SET formateo = (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(tabla.curp, '[0-9]', '') FROM tuTabla LIMIT 1);
RETURN formateo;
END ;
//
```

Posterior:

- Construimos un `SELECT` regular indicando las columnas deseadas
- La columna que deseamos formatear la pasamos como argumento de la función
- Al final para solo obtener la CURP de un usuario especifico usamos el `WHERE` antes mencionado

  ```
  SELECT formateaCURP(columnadeCurp) FROM tuTabla WHERE id = algunId;
  ```

Enlaces:

- [enlace 1](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,406891)
- [enlace 2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-function.html)

Comment: una pregunta para que sirve el  REGEXP_REPLACE?

Comment: a perdon no lo habia visto gracias

Comment: me da un error en el REGEXP_REPLACE me dice que no existe al momento de ejecutar el select me da ese error

Comment: estoy usando la 6.3 CE

Comment: a perdon me confundi es la 5.7

Comment: ooo ya entonces deja cambio de version

Comment: si esta bien orita te digo